# ILI9341 LCD for STM32F4

Tags: c++, stm32, keil, lcd, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to connect this LCD TFT display (ILI9341) to my STM32F4 using the library in this [site](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/04/library-08-ili9341-lcd-on-stm32f429-discovery-board/).

But I keep getting symbol undefined errors on keil, even though I have defined the functions I am calling using extern and added their headers and also specified their paths. Please could someone explain to me the causes of an error like this and how to best solve similar problems.

code :

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------    --
 * CMSIS-RTOS 'main' function template
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define osObjectsPublic                     // define objects in main module
#include "osObjects.h"                      // RTOS object definitions
#include "LCD_FUNCS.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_spi.h"
#include "tm_stm32f4_spi.h"

extern void TM_ILI9341_Init(void);
extern void TM_DELAY_Init(void);


/*
 * main: initialize and start the system
 */
int main (void) {
  osKernelInitialize ();                    // initialize CMSIS-RTOS

  // initialize peripherals here


    //Initialize system
    SystemInit();
    //Initialize delay
    TM_DELAY_Init();
    //Initialize ILI9341 with LTDC
    //By default layer 1 is used
    TM_ILI9341_Init();


  // create 'thread' functions that start executing,
  // example: tid_name = osThreadCreate (osThread(name), NULL);

  osKernelStart ();                         // start thread execution 
}
```

Note that I have not started implementing the functions, I am satill trying to get them to compile.

Error message :

.\Objects\PROJECT1.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol TM_ILI9341_Init (referred from main.o).
.\Objects\PROJECT1.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol TM_DELAY_Init (referred from main.o).

Comment: You aren't compiling/linking the cpp files of the library.

Comment: The cpp files are in the same folder as the header files and I have included their paths.they should be compiled automatically.

Comment: That's not how it generally works. Headers get included in your own files (and the include path is there just so that you can refer to them by file name, without the whole path). Adding a cpp file in the include path achieves exactly nothing.

Comment: I have included the cpp files themselves too in the project folder in keil.

Comment: "I have defined the functions I am calling using extern"  This is not accurate.  You need to review the difference between a definition and a declaration.  You have a declaration; the linker is looking for a definition.

Answer (score -1):

Try to comment out the `extern void TM_ILI9341_Init(void);` and `extern void TM_DELAY_Init(void);`

Comment: That won't help, he's actually trying to call them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34393001)